# Python call Powershell Invoke-RestMethod with Json as string into Body

Tags: python, json, powershell, subprocess, invoke-restmethod

```
import requests
import subprocess
import base64


credentials = "login:password"
url = f'urlXXXurl'
body = '{"id": 4986986, "key": "2df534ee-270b-4ab4-83fb-1b308febacce", ...}'


headers = '"""@{Authorization = \'Basic %s\'}"""' % base64.b64encode(credentials.encode("ascii")).decode("ascii")
command = 'powershell.exe Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri %s -ContentType application/json -Body """%s""" -Headers ( Invoke-Expression %s ) -UseBasicParsing' % (url, body.replace('"', '\"'), headers)
response = subprocess.check_call(command)
```

Is there some kind of necessary conversion, so that JSON would be recognizable by PowerShell?

Comment: You could use [`powershell.exe -EncodedCommand <base64 of UTF16le-encoded script>`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-encode-string-and-execute-with-powershell/), then you won't have to worry about double-escaping quotes. But... why not just use the `requests` module for the post request? Why call out to PowerShell in the first place?

Comment: A http request the body is a string (json).  No change on need to take you string from pything and send to PS.  You do not need to use the replace to change the double quotes.

Comment: I have very strange client-server environment where I am not able to call python requests, tried that. I can execute some subprocess.run calls though. And powershell works, I also considered cmd curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The only immediate problem with the approach in your question was the use of `"""..."""` around the `-Body` argument (resulting in a `"..."` string from PowerShell's perspective):

  - Doing so requires *two* escaping techniques: `\` (or `"""`) in order to preserve any `"` characters *as part of the PowerShell command* passed to the the (implied) `-Command` parameter of PowerShell's CLI *and* `` ` ``-escaping of the `"` chars. *embedded in the value* (`...`).
  - While you could therefore have used `` body.replace('"', '`\"') `` (note the `` ` ``), it is simpler to use `'...'` for strings,<sup>[1]</sup> given that `'` does
    not require escaping on the command line and allows embedding `"` characters as-is (albeit as `\"` via the CLI).
- There is no need for `( Invoke-Expression %s )`, given that you can formulate the string representing the `-Header` argument *directly* as a PowerShell [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) literal.
- As Mathias points out, if you want the command to output a *JSON string*, use [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) and access the output object's `.Content` property.

  - By contrast, if you use [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod), PowerShell automatically and invariably parses a JSON response into an *object graph* (which is what necessitated the `ConvertTo-Json` call in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76680500/45375), which isn't needed if you use `(Invoke-WebRequest).Content`).

Applying the above to your code, using Python v3.6+ f-strings:

```
import requests
import subprocess
import base64

credentials = 'login:password'
url = 'urlXXXurl'
body = '{"id": 4986986, "key": "2df534ee-270b-4ab4-83fb-1b308febacce", ...}'

# Construct the header as a string representing a PowerShell hashtable literal.
# Note the the use of {{ and }} to use *literal* { and } chars. in the f-string.
headers = f"@{{Authorization = 'Basic {base64.b64encode(credentials.encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')}'}}"

# Escape the " chars. in JSON as \", 
# so that the PowerShell CLI doesn't strip them.
bodyEscaped = body.replace('"', '\"')

# Note:
#  Due to use of '...' PowerShell strings, the assumption is that
#  neither header nor bodyEscaped themselves contain '
#  If they did, these embedded ' would have to be escaped as ''
command = f"""\
powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command
  (
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri '{url}' -Body '{bodyEscaped}' -Headers {headers} -Method Post -ContentType application/json -UseBasicParsing
  ).Content
"""

response = subprocess.check_call(command)
```

Note that neither the `-NoProfile` nor the `-Command` parameter of the [Windows PowerShell CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) are strictly needed here:

- `-NoProfile` bypasses profile (initialization-file) loading and is therefore both potentially faster and makes for a more predictable execution environment.
- `-Command` (`-c`) would be *implied* if not used, but is included for conceptual clarity (not least because [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the *PowerShell (Core)* CLI, now *requires* `-Command`, as it defaults to `-File`).

Finally, note that - for simplicity - what constitutes the PowerShell command is technically passed as *multiple* arguments rather than as a single string enclosed in (unescaped) `"..."`.

- If (another) *shell*, notably `cmd.exe`, were involved in the call (it isn't with `subprocess.call()`), use of `"..."` would be advisable, to prevent accidental interpretation of characters such as `&` and `|` by that shell.
- Separately, `"..."` would also be needed in the rare event that your PowerShell command has embedded strings with runs of *multiple* spaces that need to be preserved as such (without `"..."` enclosure, such runs would be folded into a single space each).

---

<sup>[1] This assumes that you don't need *PowerShell*'s string interpolation, which requires `"..."` strings.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Finally I used this approach

```
command = "powershell.exe ConvertTo-Json ( Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri %s -ContentType application/json -Body '%s' -Headers ( Invoke-Expression %s ) -UseBasicParsing )" \
                      % (url, json.dumps(self.asset).replace('"', '"""'), headers)
```

Comment: If you want the raw JSON output, then use `Invoke-WebRequest ... |ForEach-Object Content` instead of `ConvertTo-Json (Invoke-RestMethod ...)` - `Invoke-RestMethod` is designed to automatically convert JSON to an object hierarchy, which is obviously not what you want

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).